# How to avoid TextChanged event in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, textbox, viewstate, textchanged

I have a TextBox and a postback Button.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged1"     EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox><span></span>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

So, I need to fire TextChanged event only when text changed(what an irony), like it fires when EnableViewState is true. I can't unsubscribe event or subscribe it somwhere else or enable ViewState.
I've tried to save text from the TextBox in HiddenField and then check if it's changed. Here's the code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (HiddenField1.Value != TextBox1.Text) {
        HiddenField1.Value = TextBox1.Text;
        TextBox1.Text = HiddenField1.Value;
    }           
}
```

But I have no idea what to do when text is not changed and not to fire the event.

Comment: hoe do you load text box from db?

Comment: how do you load textbox then?

Comment: hmmm... i think it's loading after Page Load event.

Comment: Sorry,am still little confused,can you tell me what exactly you need?

Comment: I need TextBox with disabled ViewState behave like it is enabled, i.e. firing TextChanged event ONLY when text changed (now it fires every postback). I can't unsubscribe this event or turn ViewState on.

Comment: Avoid to do that, multiple post back to the server, very bad design, use a simple javascript for the same effect.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in saving values from TextBox when ViewState disabled. Saving it in HiddenField is not a good idea, because we can take value from HiddenField on Page_Load, but we need to take it on TextBox init. However, if we save TextBox to Session variable, this problem will disappear. Here's the code:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Session["text"] = TextBox1.Text;
}
protected void TextBox1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(Session["text"]!=null)TextBox1.Text = Session["text"].ToString();
}
```

Save values in session variable on textchanged event and restore it on textbox init. Comparison run on framework level.